# Retrieve Tool tip text from Selenium WebDriver in Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, tooltip

I have written below code to retrieve tooltip text from an application. But it's always passing the value as empty.("")
Assume the application is ToolsQA "http://demoqa.com/" and I want to take the tooltip text of the http://demoqa.com/tooltip/ "Your age"

Please see the code below which I used.

```
public String  getToolTipText(String xpath) throws InterruptedException{

        xpath = "//div[@class='inside_contain']//input";
        WebElement mainElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
        Actions act = new Actions(driver);
        //act.moveToElement(mainElement).build().perform();
        act.clickAndHold(mainElement).build().perform(); 
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        String tooltiptextreal = mainElement.getAttribute("title");

        return tooltiptextreal;
    }
```

Assertion:

```
String TooltipText = "We ask for your age only for statistical purpose.";
    Assert.assertEquals(pToolsQAWidgetTooltipPageDom.getToolTipText(), TooltipText);
```

Output:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected [We ask for your age only for statistical purpose.] but found []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

To retrieve the Tooltip text `We ask for your age only for statistical purpose.` you can use the following code block. The following code block extracts the Tooltip as `We ask for your age only for statistical purpose.` and prints on the console.

```
package demo;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Q45433269_Tooltip 
{
    @Test
    public void  getToolTipText() throws InterruptedException
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.navigate().to("http://demoqa.com/tooltip/");
        driver.findElement(By.id("age")).click();
        Actions act = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement age_purpose = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id, 'ui-id-')]/div[@class='ui-tooltip-content']"));
        act.moveToElement(age_purpose).perform();
        String tooltiptextreal = age_purpose.getText();
        System.out.println("Tooltip text is : "+tooltiptextreal);
    }
}
```

The output on the console is as:

```
Tooltip text is : We ask for your age only for statistical purposes.
PASSED: getToolTipText

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked well. One more thing to clarify. as I can see the xpath is defined as "//div[contains(@id, 'ui-id-')]/div[@class='ui-tooltip-content']" could you please clarify of how did you derive it because even we searched that xpath in inspect elements it doesn't show a possible match.

Comment: @NickW Glad to be able to help you :) If you take a closer look you will find that the `id` is dynamic. Hence I used `contains` but very next picked up the reference to the class `ui-tooltip-content`

Answer (score 0):

When you get your mouse over that input the "title" attribute gets removed (check with browser dev tool) so that you cannot obtain the proper value.

[image]

If you need "title" attribute value try removing

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
//act.moveToElement(mainElement).build().perform();
act.clickAndHold(mainElement).build().perform();
```

from your code.

Comment: I removed the part as you commented but still it gives the same result:

New Code:
public String  getToolTipText(String xpath) throws InterruptedException{
  
  WebElement mainElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
  //Actions act = new Actions(driver);
  //act.moveToElement(mainElement).build().perform();
  //act.clickAndHold(mainElement).build().perform();
  Thread.sleep(5000);
  String tooltiptextreal = mainElement.getAttribute("title");
  
  return tooltiptextreal;
 }